# TileLayout in ButtonBar skin

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

In my ButtonBar skin I use TileLayout:

`<s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" width="100%" height="100%">
       <s:layout>
     <s:TileLayout />
       </s:layout>
  </s:DataGroup>`

But this layout set max width to all ButtonBarButtons. But I dont want same width, I want behavior as in HorizontalLayout. How to solve this problem?

Comment: The point of tile layout is that they're all the same size.  You need to specify either the width/height of your 'tiles' or set the rows/columns of your layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this `FlowLayout`](http://evtimmy.com/2009/06/flowlayout-a-spark-custom-layout-example/) or [this layout](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/horizontal-multiline-layout/) can solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why HoizontalLayout won't work for you?

```
    <s:ButtonBar>
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:ButtonBar>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i need TileLayout.